# Recursive method to multiply two non-negative ints

Tags: java, recursion, multiplication

Just saw this in a past exam paper and am looking for the best way to do it since I can't figure it out. We are not allowed use multiplication in our answer, it must use repeated addition. It must also be recursive and not iterative.

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {



}
```

Can anyone help me figure this out please?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Hint*: `a + b` is equal to `a + 1 + 1 + 1...` (`+ 1` repeated `b` times)

Comment: your method name says "add" and your topic says "multiply" which is it?

Comment: It is multiplying, using recursive addition.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a == 0 ? 0 : (add(a-1, b) + b);
}
```

Comment: @Eng.Fouad That was the specification. It might be useful to make it more general, but that would also risk overcomplicating it for OP.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see "non-negative" at the begining.

Answer (score 2):

If shifts and mods are allowed, here's a fun one.

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a == 0 ? 0 : add(a >> 1, b << 1) + (a % 2 == 1 ? b : 0);
}
```

or (with an & instead of mod):

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a == 0 ? 0 : add(a >> 1, b << 1) + (a & 1 == 1 ? b : 0);
}
```

Comment: this one will only recurse lg(a) times.

Answer (score 2):

What cidermonkey has written is an implementation of [ancient Egyptian multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication), and was used at least 3700 years ago.

For example, to multiply 27 * 37, write the two numbers and repeated halve the first number and double the second:

```
27   37
13   74
 6  148
 3  296
 1  592
```

then, add the numbers in the second column which have a odd number in the first column:

```
37 + 74 + 296 + 592 = 999
```

The method still works today...  mathematics is good like that.